# Is it possible to override DateTime.Now or warn developers not to use it?

Tags: c#, .net

When running a project locally, DateTime.Now inserts the local time into the development database, which can cause problems with date comparisons and time span calculations. Currently, the only way our team can prevent this is by catching it in the pull request, and advising the developer to use DateTime.UtcNow.

Is it possible to add some sort of warning to developers in this codebase whenever they try to use DateTime.Now (maybe via an attribute?), or override the implementation of DateTime.Now so that it returns DateTime.UtcNow?

Comment: With Resharper you could create a pattern for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35898629/284240

Comment: I don't agree @FranzGleichmann. I work a lot with junior dev and code analyzer is helpful to educate. With Roslyn, it exists the analyzer [DisableDateTimeNow](https://github.com/LiamMorrow/DateTime.Now-Banisher). Just add the Nuget package.

Comment: Yup,I don't agree this question to be closed. But apparently one person can single handedly close a question now in SO. ‍♂️

Comment: If the OP or the people voting to reopen this question would explain why the proposed duplicate does not in fact answer the question, I will also vote to reopen.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann don't spread false information.  The OP can write a custom Roslyn analyzer to prevent developers from using `DateTime.Now`

Comment: @vernou should have answered instead of commenting.

Comment: @Naylor: The question [was closed at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68683368/timeline), no answer could be added.

Comment: And the proposed duplicate does appear to suggest using a Roslyn analyzer.

Comment: Ah, of course, well if it stays opened then they could answer. The duplicate does suggest Roslyn, but it doesn't include the Nuget package that @vernou pointed out which directly addresses the OP's concern with DateTime.Now

Comment: How about configuring your source control to not accept commits that contain DateTime.Now ? https://medium.com/@ripoche.b/using-global-pre-commit-hook-to-prevent-committing-unwanted-code-edbbf957ad12

Comment: @DourHighArch Marking a method obsolete does not prevent someone from using it, it merely spits out warning. Nowadays we can use analyzer to ban a method from a project, any attempt of usage will get compile error. I use it all the time to make sure everyone is using .NowUtc instead of .Now.

Comment: @Rosdi, an `Obsolete` attribute with [`IsError=true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute.iserror?view=net-5.0) will stop Roslyn or the csc compiler with an error, but it is not clear to me if this will answer the OP's question.

Comment: @DourHighArch What if the method is part of .NET library? Can we arbitrarily set any method obsolete? We don't have source code access to those.